# How order Entities by value from newly created object in JPQL select query?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

So, I have the next JPQL query:

```
SELECT NEW GroupByBooksCount(g.genreId, g.genreName, COUNT(g.genreId))
FROM Genre g
JOIN Book b ON
     g.genreId = b.genreId
GROUP BY g.genreId
```

that return me object with 3 values:

```
genreId, genreName, booksCountInGenre
```

How can I sort my result by `booksCountInGenre` parameter using JPQL?
Or maby there are some other ways to make this select?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I find the solution!

To order result set by one of constructor parameters in JPQL just set to `ORDER BY` parameter in the same form as in construcnor. Like this

```
SELECT NEW GroupByBooksCount(g.genreId, g.genreName, COUNT(g.genreId))
FROM Genre g
JOIN Book b ON
     g.genreId = b.genreId
GROUP BY g.genreId
ORDER BY COUNT(g.genreId) ASC
```

It works for me!